# What is the point of the "perl" command?

Tags: perl, command-line, cmd

When I type `perl` in any command prompt (with Perl installed on the system of course) nothing really happens. What is the point of using `perl` at the command prompt? Unlike the `python`, `lua`, and `ruby` commands it seems to do nothing.

**If it does do something, what is it and how do you use it?**

Comment: Maybe you should [look at some documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) before deriding something as pointless.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question, since there is an actual point to it. Interpreters for some other scripting languages, particularly python and lua, display a prompt when executed without arguments. The Perl interpreter doesn't, and that could be confusing for users who are accustomed to the way the `python` command behaves.

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks i just got that `^D` was needed to run the script that was entered, and yes i am accustomed to the way the python interpreter behaves.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `perl` command with no arguments compiles and runs any Perl code it sees on its standard input; it doesn't give you an interactive prompt as some other interpreters do.

A good way to try out individual Perl commands is to invoke the Perl debugger:

```
% perl -dwe 0
```

The switches are:

- `-d`   : Invoke the Perl debugger
- `-w`   : Enable warnings
- `-e 1` : Execute `0` as a Perl script (it does nothing, but leaves you in the interactive debugger).

And as Jack Maney said in his comment, you should [read the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) (`perldoc perlrun` should give you the same information locally).

But keep in mind that the primary purpose of the `perl` command is to execute Perl scripts. Perl *can* be used interactively, and one-liners such as:

```
perl -e 'print time, "\n"'
```

(which prints the current time in seconds since 1970) can be very useful, but that's not its main use.  Normally you'd have a script with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

(or equivalent) as the first line.

Comment: Nice trick that `dwe 0` (although I prefer just a series of `-e`'s).